# uploading an image in codeigniter with validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
public function store(){                            
        $id=$this->input->post('id'); 
        $_POST['date_created']=date('Y-m-d');       
        if ($this->form_validation->run('registration') === TRUE)
        {                  
            $_POST['password']=  md5($_POST['password']);
            if(!empty($_FILES['profile_img']['name']))
            {             
                echo 'file set ..1<br>';
                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('profile_img'))
                {                                  
                    echo 'file uploading failed ..2';
                    $error = $this->upload->display_errors(); 
                    echo $error;
                    //here its not load the view.
                    $this->template->load('templates/template','emp/add-emp',$error);

                }
                else
                {
                    $img = $this->upload->data();
                    $file_name ='images/'.$img['file_name'];
                    $data=  elements(array('fname','lname','email','password','state','city','mobile','emp_role','profile_img','date_created'),$_POST,$file_name);                    
                }        
            }
            else
            {   
                echo 'file not set..3';
                $data= elements(array('fname','lname','email','password','state','city','mobile','emp_role','date_created'), $_POST);                     
            }  

            if(empty($id)){
                    echo 'Add data ..4';
                    $this->emp_model->set($data);
                   // $this->crud->insert('info',$data);
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Inserted Succesfully ");</script>';
                    redirect('employee/add','refresh');
            }
            else{
                    echo 'Update data ..5';
                    $this->emp_model->set($data,$id);
                   // update('info', $data, 'id', $id);
                   //$this->crud->update('info',$data,'id',$id);
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Updated Succesfully ");</script>';
                    redirect('employee','refresh');
               }    
        }
        else
        {               
            if(empty($id)){                    
                echo 'add data validation falid ..';
                $this->add();
            }
            else{
                echo 'edit data validation falid ..';
                $this->edit($id);                    
            }          
        }
    }
```

problem is that when file uploading failed means when file not image or excced file limit it comes into display errors function but i can't load my view ...
so please tell me whats problem should there?

Comment: Are you trying to simply show a validation error or are you trying to redirect?

Comment: no i am trying to redirect ..

Comment: temprory  i  echo $error

Comment: If you are trying to redirect, just use `redirect()`

Comment: but it will not display error in view
i want to display error

Comment: set flashdata: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 2):

Using flashdata and redirect can redirect you while holding your error message for the next request:

```
if(! $this->upload->do_upload($file_name){
       $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
       $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '$error');
       redirect('/somewhere', 'refresh');
  }
```